# How to create an input-only parameter for an Angularjs directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a directive, that has some configurable properties. To do this I'm adding this to the directive declaration:

```
...
scope: {
    maxColumns: '=',
    minColumns: '=',
},
...
```

This way I can simply use the directive like so:

```
<my-directive max-columns="maxColOnScope" min-columns="minColOnScope"></my-directive>
```

but I also want to be able to just do this:

```
<my-directive max-columns="4" min-columns="2"></my-directive>
```

This last situation works, but gives the Angular error: $compile:nonassign saying that the value 4 is not bindable and can thus not be used for two way binding.

That's all great, but I hate that now I have to either:

- Ignore the error message
- Never use static values, but instead always supply them via the scope
- Use the @-binding which in turn will turn any input into a string and also forces me to use {{ }} whenever I DO want to use a value on the scope...

None of these options seem particularly appealing to me. Am I missing something or is there just no way to do what I want?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem I got hit by the that-was-kind-of-stupid train.

In addition to the scope declaration:

```
scope: {
    maxColumns: '=',
    minColumns: '=',
},
```

I also had the `bindToController` value set to true which caused the values to be added as properties to the controller.

This in itself is exactly what I want, but I accidentally set the value in the controller by using a single equals sign in a comparison...

Only because the value changes does AngularJs give me the message that the value is read only. Fixing the bug removed the error message.

I'll leave the question here with this answer for future dummies ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use (single) quotes for static values.

```
<my-directive max-columns="'4'" min-columns="'2'"></my-directive>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't do little more than change the error message :)
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign?p0=%274%27&p1=myDirective